# Problema con pack() y setTitle() en JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un programa que tiene una interfaz gráfica no muy elaborada. Estoy trabajando con un JFrame en particular.

A la hora de agregar todos los componentes no hay problema alguno, el LayoutManager que uso hace todo bien (el fabuloso MigLayout). Antes de terminar, le seteo el título a la ventana con `setTitle()` y luego uso `pack()` para darle forma a todo.

En la ventana, todos los componentes están bien posicionados y los tamaños de los mismos están bien, pero el título del JFrame no se alcanza a ver completamente y no sé de qué manera hacer que la ventana sea más ancha para que se pueda apreciar. El título no es largo, son aproximadamente 12 caracteres pero sólo se alcanzan a ver unos pocos porque por los elementos que tiene el JPanel, el JFrame queda angosto. ¿Tendría que hacer uso de `setPreferredSize()` para el JFrame y ponerle un ancho "hardcodeado" donde el título se vea completo? He visto en varios lugares que métodos como `setSize()`, `setPreferredSize()` y similares son considerados "mala práctica" para lo que son interfaces gráficas.

Para que se entienda lo que digo, hice un ejemplo simple y ejecutable (con una estructura muy similar a la que debería tener la ventana) para que puedan probarlo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Main {

    private static JFrame myFrame;
    private static JPanel masterPanel, leftPanel, rightPanel, southPanel;
    private static JButton button1, button2;
    private static ArrayList<JSpinner> spinners;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFrame = new JFrame();

        masterPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        leftPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2"));
        rightPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2"));
        southPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        button1 = new JButton("BOTÓN 1");
        button2 = new JButton("BOTÓN 2");

        spinners = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            spinners.add(new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 5, 1)));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < (spinners.size() / 2); i++) {
            leftPanel.add(new JLabel("TEXTO " + (i + 1)));
            leftPanel.add(spinners.get(i), "wrap");
        }

        for (int i = (spinners.size() / 2); i < spinners.size(); i++) {
            rightPanel.add(new JLabel("TEXTO " + (i + 1)));
            rightPanel.add(spinners.get(i));
        }

        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);

        masterPanel.add(southPanel, "south");
        masterPanel.add(leftPanel, "west");
        masterPanel.add(rightPanel, "center, span");

        myFrame.add(masterPanel);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setTitle("TÍTULO DE PRUEBA");
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Para los que no tengan MigLayout, les dejo una imagen de cómo queda la ventana:

[image: Problema con pack() y setTitle() en JFrame]

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

[`pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) básicamente pone el tamaño al `JFrame` basándose en las dimensiones de los componentes y layouts que contiene.

En el caso concreto de [*MigLayout*](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html), el cual es el que está poniendo los componentes en su sitio, dispone de un *constraint* llamado ***gapx*** que le permite ensanchar el tamaño del componente al que se le aplique (*fue lo que entendí al leer la descripción en el apartado 'Layout Constraints'*).

De tal manera que para lograr lo que buscas, se debe especificar ese *constraint* así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (spinners.size() / 2); i++) {
  leftPanel.add(new JLabel("TEXTO " + (i + 1)));
  leftPanel.add(spinners.get(i), "wrap, gapx 20");
}
```

Entonces `leftPanel` queda, en ese ejemplo, con 20*px* mas de ancho que por ultimo `pack()` le va a aplicar a las dimensiones del `JFrame` específicamente a su medida de ancho; por fin podrá verse completo el titulo.

**Edito:**

Es perfectamente posible también vía constructor:

`leftPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2, gapx 30"));`